# Axios запрашивает не в том порте

Tags: reactjs, axios

```js
const [products, setProducts] = React.useState([]); React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get('api/products');
      setProducts(result.data);
    };
    fetchData();},
 []);
```

вот package

```
{"name": "client","proxy": "http://localhost:5000","version": "0.1.0","private": true,"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.2.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"},"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"},"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"]},"browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

после обновления страницы получаю ошибку GET http://localhost:3000/api/products 404 (Not Found)
хотя данные находятся на порте - 5000

Comment: И где вы сказали axios-у откуда брать данные? Он магически не умеет угадывать.

Comment: Так задал же. await axios.get('api/products'); меня беспокоит почему он (axios) пошёл их искать на порт 3000 хотя в package я задал "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"

Comment: Кинь в axios config порт нужный @ПочтиСоловей

Comment: а где этот конфиг я найти смогу? Или его надо прописать?

Comment: прописать, да. Глянь тут https://axios-http.com/docs/config_defaults @ПочтиСоловей

Comment: Рекомендую почитать документацию (как рекомендуют выше), либо прописать полный путь.

Comment: Спасибо! понял,хорошо